# How to use public function frontend Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have a custom function in magento, how I can do in the frontend to see the public functions values?

**Function:**

```
public function getOptionsWithValues()
{
    $attributes = $item->getOptionByCode('attributes')->getValue();

    if (!$attributes)
    {
        return null;
    }

    $attributes = unserialize($attributes);
    $options = array();

    foreach ($attributes as $attr_id => $attr_value)
    {
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attr_id);

        $attr_options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);   

        foreach ($attr_options as $option)
        {
            if ($option['value'] == $attr_value)
            {
                $options[$attribute->getFrontendLabel()] = $option['label'];
            }
        }
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can have this code in the Helper class of your module. You can then call it like this: `Mage::helper("helpername")->getOptionsWithValues();`

Comment: I add this in core wishlist, /app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Item/Option.php and I want to display the attributes values in frontend

Comment: Dont hack code into core files. Create a module, insert the code above into the `Data.php` (which is your helper class for your module) and call it in frontend anywhere you want like I showed you in my first comment.

Comment: don't worry is not a problem about this, all I want is to tell me if you know how I can display $option['label'] in the frontend

Comment: `echo $options["attribute_name"]` ?

Comment: :) but that is array value, and this function is get all attributes that is related with the actual product, so we can;t use there attribute_name

Comment: How would I know what `$item` is? It isnt even in the parameters.

Comment: take a look here:

* @var Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item $item */
$item = $this->getItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();

Comment: Sorry I really dont understand what you're trying to do. Can you please add clarification about this in the question (not comment section)?

Comment: please take a look at my second comment, I will paste it again here: "
 
I add this in core wishlist, /app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Item/Option.php and I want to display the attributes values in frontend", is clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you added this code in /app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Item/Option.php. So you can instantiate this class using the factory methods like

```
$itemOption = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item_option');
```

If you try this code in a separate file and echo `get_class($itemOption)`, you will see the class name. Now you can access the function directly by the object like `$itemOption -> getOptionsWithValues()`.

But you should never make changes in the core files directly rather you could copy the same folder structure in the local folder or rewrite the model class which you want to override.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento if you want to display certain values by calling a function. you need to define that function in block

- .phtml file : from this template file you can call any block function.

If this function is defined in a block. call it from phtml file using this code.

```
$blockObj = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('block_name');
```

Call the block function

```
echo $blockObj->getOptionsWithValues();
```

Comment: sorry but I don;t understand? what is the block name for wishlist?

Comment: block name is defined in layout. Example :
<block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">

Comment: we talk about the default Magento wishlist, for that I ask you to tell me exactly the block name.